# Can i update BaseCase class in seleniumbase framework?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, seleniumbase

I'm using selenium base framework for automation. we have inbuilt class as BaseCase. Here, my application has different set of users with desired access.can i create a method for logging to different set of users in BaseCase and call it in test case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you just described:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class SwagLabsTests(BaseCase):
    def login_to_swag_labs(self, username="standard_user"):
        """Login to Swag Labs and verify success."""
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        if username not in self.get_text("#login_credentials"):
            self.fail("Invalid user for login: %s" % username)
        self.type("#user-name", username)
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        self.click('input[type="submit"]')
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_element('.inventory_item:contains("Sauce Labs Backpack")')

    def test_swag_labs_basic_flow(self):
        """This test checks functional flow of the Swag Labs store."""
        self.login_to_swag_labs(username="standard_user")
```

(From [test_swag_labs.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_swag_labs.py))